# I need to display table data in my custom module at the front end of the site. Its saying wrong argument for $collection

Tags: database, module, custom, table

/*Showdata.php Controller\Index
*/

```
<?php

namespace Eaglerocket\Customquote\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Showdata extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

/*post_requirements.phtml*/

```
<?php 
$myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Eaglerocket\Customquote\Block\Blockname');

$currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct(); 
  $collection = $block->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $item)
          echo $item->getId(); 

 ?>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="popupButton" data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#myModal"><?php echo __('Post Requirement')?></button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo __('Get Quote')?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBaseUrl().'customquote/index/submit')?>" method="post">


         
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name"><?php echo __('Product Name');?>:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $currentProduct->getName();?>">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="requirement"><?php echo __('Question') ?> :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="<?php echo __('Enter name')?>" name="question" 
        value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBaseUrl().'customquote/index/submit')?>">
      
     <!--   -->
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="requirement"><?php echo __('Answer') ?> :</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="requirement" name="answer">
        </textarea>
            
<!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="answer" 
        value="<?php //echo $currentProduct->getName();?>"> -->  
</div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo __('Submit')?></button>
    </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
  require(['jquery', 'Eaglerocket_Customquote/js/mymodal-component'],
      function ($) {
          return;
      }
  );
  </script>
```

/*customquote_index_showdata.xml  view\frontend\layout*/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Eaglerocket\Customquote\Block\Showdata" name="showdata"
                   template="Eaglerocket_Customquote::catalog/product/post_requirements.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

/*Showdata.php  Block/*/

```
<?php

namespace Eaglerocket\Customquote\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Eaglerocket\Customquote\Model\ResourceModel\Extension\CollectionFactory;

class Showdata extends Template
{

    public $collection;

    public function __construct(Context $context, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->collection->create();
    }

}
```

Comment: To fix this problem, you can simply add getData() in return $collection.

Comment: Have you tried by doing print_r($block->getCollection()->getData()); die(); ?

Comment: Call to a member function getData() on null this I got

Comment: 176 679 344 anydesk id if anyone can solve? thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. I am connecting

Comment: I am not able to connect in above id.

Comment: 176 679 344 please try again

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: May i get your anydesk id to check whether its connecting from my side or not?

Comment: you shared mine, kindly share yours

Comment: Sorry, 994 505 000

Comment: its showing internet issue except it everything else is working Do you have team viewer?

Comment: No, i am installing team viewer.

Comment: 209944529 and pass is   f27r7iyn

Comment: incompatible team viewer versions

Comment: free version I downloaded and you?

Comment: Same here. Downloaded free version

Comment: please try anydesk again it may work now

Comment: Not working anydesk too.

Comment: it is saying you are offline

Comment: Internet is working properly from my side. And also anydesk is open here

Comment: Can you show your model, resource model and collection class?

Comment: If my answer is correct then please upvote so other community members can review.

Comment: @kks Can you please upvote my answer?

Comment: Done @ZealousWeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is proper. But in your file post_requirements.phtml , current block is not "`Eaglerocket\Customquote\Block\Showdata`" so you can not get data from   `$collection = $block->getCollection();`

So what you need to do is, you have to call collection block in the current block file or using object manager like below.

```
<?php 
$showDataBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Eaglerocket\Customquote\Block\Showdata');

$collection = $showDataBlock->getCollection();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->getData());
die();

?>
```

Please check now your table data.

Comment: don't use object manager. it;s not good practice

Comment: I had already told him to call block is in current block. I had just shown him

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. only change the model name **Factory** to your correct model name factory like **CustomModelFactory**

> **Block\Showdata.php**

```
<?php

namespace Eaglerocket\Customquote\Block;

class Showdata extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Eaglerocket\Customquote\Model\<ModelName>Factory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

> **post_requirements.phtml**

```
<?php
    $collection = $block->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
      echo $item->getQuestion(); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 1
            [question] => 
ytrtyetrsyt


            [priority] => 2
            [tags] => jhbjb
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 2021-06-16 17:57:35
            [updated_at] => 2021-06-17 07:29:24
        )

    ) In this format I am getting the table data and I only need question field. Since everything is working here in object form so how to capture the question field?

Comment: try in foreach $item->getQuestion();

Comment: check updated answer